# Get data into textbox using stored procedure in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to get data into a textbox using a stored procedure:

```
var q = objcontext.sploadloandata(comboBox1.Text);
txtcustname.Text = "what to do here";
txtaddress.Text = "what to do here";
txtmobile.Text = "what to do here";
txtemailid.Text = "what to do here";
```

This code is my stored procedure, please check and get me out of this problem

```
alter proc sploadloandata
    @customerid nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @today datetime
    SET @today = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, current_timestamp), 0)

    select 
        a.custid, b.name, b.mobile, b.phone, a.eligibleamt, 
        a.loanamt, a.interest, a.validity,
        datediff(day, a.cdate, @today) as No_Of_Days,
        round(a.loanamt * a.interest * datediff(day, a.cdate, @today) / 36500, 2) as SI,
        round(a.loanamt * a.interest * datediff(day, a.cdate, @today) / 36500, 2) + a.loanamt as CHECKsi
    from 
        tblLoanEntrydetails a, tbl_customer b
    where 
        a.custid = b.cid 
        and b.cid = @customerid
    order by 
        a.fororderdate desc
end
```

Comment: This question needs a bit more to it, like, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to put properties of q into different textboxes?

Comment: You've successfully demonstrated how using `var` can lead to obfuscated code.

Comment: @VarmaAmit what have you done on your end besides posting code that does not really pertain to anything close to what you are trying to achieve? have you executed a google search.. if you are not familiar with how to call a stored procedure from C# Code behind, then how can one expect you to understand something a little bit more complex than using `Linq` there are thousands of examples online in regards to how to return data from a database using C# as well as how to loop through the results set using a DataAdapter etc..

Comment: @ MethodMan : i have edit my query,and i know how to handle using DataAdapter,But i want in LINQ to SQL.So please check and reply me if possible

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What's your problem? Does q not contain the data from the SPROC? Or do you not know how to set txtcustname.Text = q.name?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger MY SPPROC return some results,that result i want to call on textboxes on the form, but with use of LINQ

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger  thanks sir for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

I find the correct solution...
please check this....

First of all replace the query that i had write

```
Old Query : var q = objcontext.sploadloandata(comboBox1.Text);
New Query :  var q = (from data1 in objcontext.sploadloandata(comboBox1.Text)
                select data1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, i get all the data into the textbox

```
txtcustname.Text = q.name;
txtnetweight.Text = q.weight;
txtmobile.Text = q.mobile;
txtloanamt.Text = q.loanamt;
```

Comment: FirstorDefault will return null if there are no records. Accessing the name property on q would then throw an error. You might want to check for null first.